# Rotating a finished animation

Tags: rendering, animation

How can a finished animation be rotated? Or, should the animation process be redone according to the new rotation?
I rotated the whole scene but the resulting animation does not change.

Comment: ...not sure to get it... orbit the camera around it?

Comment: Can you describe a little more what the animation is contructed of (single armature? multiple objects? simulations?)

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I hope the following clarifies my question. I have created an animation of a bullet smashing a wall of glass from right to left. Now I want to run this animation rotated by 90 degrees, from bottom to top. I rotated the whole scene by 90 degrees, with all the objects including the camera, but unfortunately the camera view does not change and consequently the animation itself keeps running from right to left.

Answer (score 2):

You can always create an empty, and parent your animated object to it. Select first your object(s), and at last the new empty. Then, press *Strg+P* and select *Object (Keep Transform)*. After that, you can rotate or move the empty around, and your animation will follow.

Comment: Hello Grimm, thanks for your answer which I followed but unfortunately the animation keeps running from right to left. One more detail is that I have 2 scenes which I have composed to be rendered one after the other, each one with different rendering parameters (CPU/GPU, No. of tiles etc.).

Comment: As always: In this case, consider [uploading your blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), so that someone can have a closer look at it.

Comment: Thank you Grimm, since the file is too heavy to upload, I shared it on Google Drive. Here is the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B38XeXTxK3ftUktYNWlTMWRXTWM/view?usp=sharing